Minhag of reading end of Parshat Emor with an undertone
Good morning,
Last Shabbat for Parshat Emor, I noticed that our experienced baal Koreh read the end of the Parsha about the episode of the Mekalel aka the blasphemer with an undertone. After services, I asked him why and told me it was the way he was taught to do it without quoting any clear source.
Is it a widespread custom to do so? If yes, a source would be very appreciated.
